# Are classes inheriting from DispatcherObject thread-safe or thread-unsafe?

Tags: .net, wpf, thread-safety

In **WPF4 Unleashed** Adam Nathan states:

> Most WPF classes derive from DispatcherObject and are therefore
>   inherently **thread-unsafe**.

**Professional WPF Programming** claims the opposite:

> DispatcherObject is the lowest level class in the framework hierarchy,
>   and because almost all objects inherit from it, most objects are
>   inherently **thread-safe**

MSDN on DispatcherObject:

> Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the
>   DispatcherObject directly. To access a DispatcherObject from a thread
>   other than the thread the DispatcherObject was created on, call Invoke
>   or BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher the DispatcherObject is associated
>   with.

Based on MSDN description it looks like **WPF4 Unleashed** quote was either a typo or Nathan was just wrong and the **Professional WPF Programming** authors were right...

Anyway, are classes inheriting from DispatcherObject inherently thread-safe or inherently thread-unsafe?

EDIT:

MSDN also states:

> Subclasses of DispatcherObject that need to enforce thread safety can
>   do so by calling VerifyAccess on all public methods. This guarantees
>   the calling thread is the thread that the DispatcherObject was created
>   on.

This indirectly confirms that **WPF4 Unleashed** claim was accurate after all...

Comment: Depends on your definition of *thread-safe*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [depends what you mean by thread-safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx), but I'd favour the view of WPF4 Unleashed - based on the MSDN description.

The documentation says that you can *only* access members of the `DispatcherObject` on a particular thread - so it's unsafe to use it from arbitrary threads. That sounds like it's a thread-unsafe type to me.

On the other hand, you *could* consider that if a `DispatcherObject` is used correctly, the code *within* the class doesn't have to take thread safety into account, as it should only be invoked from a single thread.

So in some sense it's "thread-unsafe from the outside, thread-safe from the inside". I would prefer to use a term which is more descriptive: the classes have *thread affinity*.

Comment: But if "Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the DispatcherObject directly", doesn't it make it thread-safe because it cannot be accessed from a thread other than the thread Dispatcher was created on, the UI thread effectively?

Comment: @kzen: It can't be *correctly* accessed from any other thread - but there's nothing to *stop* you from trying to do it in code. It'll just blow up at execution time if you're lucky or work *some* of the time if you're not. It's like saying that `IDisposable` implementations are naturally resource-safe: they are if you use them properly, but you've still got to put the work in to make sure you dispose of them...

Comment: Excellent post by Eric, thanks for the link... threading is soo much fun ;)

Comment: @kzen: "Excellent post by Eric" is pretty much a tautology ;)

Comment: Where no one reaches.. Jon Skeet reaches !